# What's the best way to add two matrices using overload?

Tags: c++, matrix

I have defined one matrix class, and overloaded the + operator to be able to add instances of this class together.

```
class Matrix{
public:
vector<vector<int>> a;


Matrix & operator+(const Matrix& b)
{                
    vector<vector<int>>::const_iterator it0=b.a.begin();
    vector<vector<int>>::iterator it1=this->a.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator it2=it1->begin();
    vector<int>::iterator it3=it1->end();
    vector<int>::const_iterator it01=it0->begin();

    for(it1;it1!=this->a.end();it1++)
        {
        it2=it1->begin();
        it3=it1->end();
        it01=it0->begin();
        it0++;
             // a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),ret.begin()
        std::transform(it2,it3,it01,it2,std::plus<int>());
    }
            return  *this;
}

};
```

But then, there is also another way of doing this,

```
class Matrix{
public:
vector<vector<int> > a;

Matrix & operator + (const Matrix &y) {

 for (int m=0; m<y.a.size(); ++m) {
    for (int n=0; n<y.a[0].size(); ++n) {
        this->a[m][n] = this->a[m][n] + y.a[m][n];
    }
}

return *this;
}};
```

The second form is shorter, but uses arrays directly, while the first one uses iterators. Maybe it's possible to do this with iterators in a shorter way, I'm not sure. I've tested with simple cases and they seem to be equally efficient. 
What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Whatever you think is more readable is "the best way." If both ways perform the same, just choose whatever looks clearer to you.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the second approach as it is more concise and clearer what the code does. If you are using c++11, you could consider using a [range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to make things even clearer.

Comment: Don't you mean `+=` for the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-trivial classes (such as classes including a `std::vector`), in-place operations are often cheaper than allocating a new object and then (presumably) destroying one or both of the arguments. However, aggressive use of rvalue reference overloads can somewhat mitigate this.

Note that regardless of which function implementation I used, I would not use *nested* `std::vector`s - I would either use a single `std::vector` or better a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` and then calculate the index as `y*w+x` (remember to bounds-check *first*).